# What function in the std library is there to binary search a vector and find an element?

Tags: c++, vector, std, binary-search

I've got a node struct

```
struct Node{CString text, int id;};
```

in a sorted vector.

I'm wondering if there's a function in algorithm that will do a binary search of the vector and find an element.

Comment: Are you sure about the comma between CString? Shouldn't that be a semicolon?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`std::binary_search()` will tell you if a value exists in the container.

`std::lower_bound()/std::upper_bound()` will return an iterator to the first/last occurrence of a value.

Your objects need to implement `operator<` for these algorithms to work.

Comment: or you need to use the other overload for `binary_search` and provide a comparator at the 4th parameter. This needs to be the same comparator you used to sort with.

Comment: "Unlike lower_bound, for upper_bound the value pointed by the iterator returned by this function cannot be **equivalent** to val, only greater." How can upper_bound return the last occurence of val??

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there's a function called "binary_search" std::binary_search

You give it first, last and a value or a predicate.

See [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0520__STL-Algorithms-Binary-search/Usebinarysearchtolocateavalueinavector.htm) for a sample

Combine that with [Martin York's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369211/is-there-a-search-in-algorithm-ive-got-a-sorted-vector-and-im-looking-for-speci#369237) operator== and you should be OK (alternatively you can write a predicate functor

Comment: Actually for binary search, you need an operator<, not operator==

Comment: boost::bind(&Node::text, _1) < key  :)

Comment: Also note it does not find the element.
It just test for existance.

Comment: huh that's weird. why does it do that?

Comment: might be there multiple times.  You can use lower_bound and upper_bound to find where.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a sorted vector<Node>
Why not use a map. This is a sorted container. So any search done on this via std::find() automatically has the same properties as a binary search.

Comment: If your data is stable (no ongoing additions/deletions), it is more memory efficient to use the vector. If you need to interact with other parts of the system that expect a vector.  Or you need to access the data by index.  Or the data is accessed in a tight loop, where memory locality is important.

Comment: "A sorted vector lets you iterate through the contents in order.":  So does a map.  (for (std::map<int>::iterator i = map.begin(); i != map.end(); ++i) ...)

Comment: a map also does't deal as smoothly with multiple instances of the key.

Comment: It lets you iterate in order of key. A closer analogy to a sorted vector is std::multiset.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::equal_range` to find a range of elements in a sorted vector.  `std::equal_range` returns a `std::pair` of iterators, giving you a range in the vector of elements equal to the argument you provide.  If the range is empty, then your item isn't in the vector, and the length of the range tells you how many times your item appears in the vector.

Here is an example using ints instead of `struct Node`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> sorted = { 1, 2, 2, 5, 10 };

    auto range = std::equal_range(sorted.begin(), sorted.end(), 20);
    // Outputs "5 5"
    std::cout << std::distance(sorted.begin(), range.first) << ' '
              << std::distance(sorted.begin(), range.second) << '\n';

    range = std::equal_range(sorted.begin(), sorted.end(), 5);
    // Outputs "3 4"
    std::cout << std::distance(sorted.begin(), range.first) << ' '
              << std::distance(sorted.begin(), range.second) << '\n';

    range = std::equal_range(sorted.begin(), sorted.end(), -1);
    // Outputs "0 0"
    std::cout << std::distance(sorted.begin(), range.first) << ' '
              << std::distance(sorted.begin(), range.second) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

To make this work with `struct Node` you'll either have to provide an `operator <`  for `struct Node` or pass in a comparator to `std::equal_range`.  You can do that by providing a lambda as an argument to `std::equal_range` to compare your structs.

```
std::vector<Node> nodes = { Node{"hello", 5}, Node{"goodbye", 6} };
Node searchForMe { "goodbye", 6 };
auto range = std::equal_range(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(), searchForMe,
                               [](Node lhs, Node rhs) { return lhs.id < rhs.id; });
```